# cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++

Tags: c++, python, gcc, swig

I am building a C++ extension for use in Python. I am seeing this warning being generated during the compilation process - when a type:

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

What is causing it, and how do I fix it?

BTW, here is a copy of my setup file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

    """
    setup.py file for SWIG example
    """

    from distutils.core import setup, Extension


    example_module = Extension('_foolib',
                               sources=['example_wrap.cxx', 
                                        '../wrapper++/src/Foo.cpp'
                                       ],
                               libraries=["foopp"]
                               )

    setup (name = 'foolib',
           version = '0.1',
           author      = "Me, Myself and I",
           description = """Example""",
           ext_modules = [example_module],
           py_modules = ["example"],
           )
```

I am using gcc 4.4.3 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I can answer part of the question, why you're getting the message.

Something in your build process is invoking gcc on a C++ source file with the option `-Wstrict-prototypes`.  For C and Objective-C, this causes the compiler to warn about old-style function declarations that don't declare the types of arguments.

For C++, this option doesn't make sense; such declarations aren't even allowed by the language (prototypes are mandatory).

(I don't know why the message mentions Ada; `-Wstrict-prototypes` makes even less sense for Ada than for C++. It's not a huge deal, but I've submitted [this bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51115), marked as RESOLVED/FIXED as of 2015-12-06.)

The solution should be to remove the `-Wstrict-prototypes` option from the invocation of gcc.  But since you're not invoking gcc directly, it's difficult to know how to do that.

I was able to reproduce the warning using your `setup.py`, after manually creating a dummy `example_wrap.cxx` file:

```
% python setup.py build_ext -i
running build_ext
building '_foolib' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c example_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/example_wrap.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
...
```

So it's probably a minor bug in Python's `build_ext`.

But since it's only a warning, not a fatal error, I'd say you can safely ignore it. gcc warns about the meaningless option, but then it just ignores it.

**EDIT**:

Looking through the Python-2.7.2 sources, this section of `configure.in` might be the culprit:

```
case $GCC in
yes)
    if test "$CC" != 'g++' ; then
        STRICT_PROTO="-Wstrict-prototypes"
    fi
```

(I'm assuming that's invoked when using `build_ext`.)

It turns on the `-Wstrict-prototypes` option only if the compiler is *not* being invoked as `g++` -- but in your case it's using the `gcc` command to compile C++ source code.  And in `Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py`, `build_extension()` doesn't pay attention to the source file language when invoking `self.compiler.compile()`, only when invoking `self.compiler.link_shared_object()`.  (Which seems odd; for compilers other than gcc, you wouldn't necessarily be able to use the same command to compile C and C++ -- and it makes more sense to use the `g++` command anyway, even if you're not linking.)

UPDATE: A Python bug report was submitted: https://bugs.python.org/issue9031, and closed as a duplicate of this one: https://bugs.python.org/issue1222585, which is still open as I write this.

But as I said, it's only a warning and you can probably safely ignore it.  Perhaps the Python maintainers can use the above information to fix the problem in a future release.

Comment: Now that's some mighty fine spelunking! Thanks for going to the trouble of sniffing that out. I'll submit it to the Python maintainers.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: Cool, please follow up here with any feedback you get.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: FYI, I've reported a bug against gcc for the fact that the option is accepted for Ada (this isn't directly relevant to the current question).  http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51115

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: My gcc bug report is marked RESOLVED/FIXED as of 2015-12-06

Comment: For reference there is a python ticket for this bug [issue9031](https://bugs.python.org/issue9031) which redirects to a more general  distutils and C++ issue: [issue1222585](https://bugs.python.org/issue1222585)

Answer (score 24):

Removing -Wstrict-prototypes from the OPT environment variable has no effect. What works is to subclass `build_ext` as follows:

```
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
from distutils.sysconfig import customize_compiler

class my_build_ext(build_ext):
    def build_extensions(self):
        customize_compiler(self.compiler)
        try:
            self.compiler.compiler_so.remove("-Wstrict-prototypes")
        except (AttributeError, ValueError):
            pass
        build_ext.build_extensions(self)
```

and then use `my_build_ext` inside the `setup` function:

```
setup(cmdclass = {'build_ext': my_build_ext})
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was the command I was looking for.  Also works with setuptools, fwiw.

Comment: Not sure the `customize_compiler` call or try/except are needed.

Comment: The try catch block ensures that this still works on operating systems like Windows that use MSVCCompiler that doesn't have the `compiler_so` property.

Answer (score 14):

`-Wstrict-prototypes` option is read by distutils from `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/config/Makefile` as part of OPT variable. It seems hackish, but you can override it by setting `os.environ['OPT']` in your setup.py.

Here is a code that seems not too harmful:

```
import os
from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_vars

(opt,) = get_config_vars('OPT')
os.environ['OPT'] = " ".join(
    flag for flag in opt.split() if flag != '-Wstrict-prototypes'
)
```

Answer (score 14):

This is a Python 3.x solution with setuptools.

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


# Avoid a gcc warning below:
# cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid
# for C/ObjC but not for C++
class BuildExt(build_ext):
    def build_extensions(self):
        if '-Wstrict-prototypes' in self.compiler.compiler_so:
            self.compiler.compiler_so.remove('-Wstrict-prototypes')
        super().build_extensions()

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'build_ext': BuildExt},
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 13):

The following code fragment in setup.py will remove all instances of this pesky flag:

```
# Remove the "-Wstrict-prototypes" compiler option, which isn't valid for C++.
import distutils.sysconfig
cfg_vars = distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars()
for key, value in cfg_vars.items():
    if type(value) == str:
        cfg_vars[key] = value.replace("-Wstrict-prototypes", "")
# ==================================
```

Answer (score 2):

More specifically, distutils uses the same options that python was built with, you can add options using `extra_compile_args` in creating the `distutils.core.Extension` but there does not appear to be a way to remove existing arguments in gcc or distutils.

See http://bugs.python.org/issue9031 for details, it has been closed as a duplicate of http://bugs.python.org/issue1222585, but 9031 details this aspect of the problem

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of anyone arriving here after trying to install pydoop under pypy, this solution which was adopted in pydoop 1.0.0:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var
_UNWANTED_OPTS = frozenset(['-Wstrict-prototypes'])
os.environ['OPT'] = ' '.join(
    _ for _ in get_config_var('OPT').strip().split() if _ not in _UNWANTED_OPTS
```

breaks the installation under pypy because pypy sysconfig does not supply the 'OPT' variable at all, causing it to abort when it tries to apply strip() to None. Solution is just to comment out the whole block.